# field_data_commerce_line_items vs commerce_line_item in Drupal Commerce

Tags: database, drupal-7, commerce

I've realized that there are two tables with similar names in my DB:
`field_data_commerce_line_items` and `commerce_line_item`.

Can someone explain the purpose or reason of having them? I mean the difference between them.

My understanding is that `field_data_commerce_line_items` is a reference field on an order that references a line in the `commerce_line_item` table on `field_data_commerce_line_items.commerce_line_items_line_item_id = commerce_line_item.line_item_id`.

However still not getting the overall picture.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal an entity can reference multiple entities via a field reference. The references aren't necessarily unique, but the entities are.

`field_data_commerce_line_items` is a multi-value field reference that associates Line Item entities to a specific Order.

`commerce_line_item` represents the unique Line Item entity.